# Writing a function for x * sin(3/x) in python

Tags: python, sympy

I have to write a function, s(x) = x * sin(3/x) in python that is capable of taking single values or vectors/arrays, but I'm having a little trouble handling the cases when x is zero (or has an element that's zero). This is what I have so far:

```
def s(x):
    result = zeros(size(x))
    for a in range(0,size(x)):
        if (x[a] == 0):
            result[a] = 0
        else:
            result[a] = float(x[a] * sin(3.0/x[a]))
    return result
```

Which...doesn't work for x = 0. And it's kinda messy. Even worse, I'm unable to use sympy's integrate function on it, or use it in my own simpson/trapezoidal rule code. Any ideas?

When I use `integrate()` on this function, I get the following error message: `"Symbol" object does not support indexing.`

Comment: well the function is not defined for x = 0

Comment: But the limit of the function at x = 0 is 0, and that's what the professor wants the value of 0 to be.

Comment: so add a comment that checks if the input is 0 and in that case return 0

Comment: Python can't really represent a mathematical function that's "undefined" at a certain value - if you try to divide by zero, you'll just get a `ZeroDivisonError`. If your professor wants this function to return 0 on `x=0`, you'll just have to explicitly check for that input.

Comment: Okay. Now when I rewrite the function to just `return x*sin(3.0/x)` i still get the same `"Symbol" object does not support indexing`, which is strange because it works on two other functions that I am passing the same symbolic variable into, and those integrate just fine.

Comment: Show how you are using `integrate` with this function.

Comment: `s_exact = sp.integrate(HW8.s(x), (x, 0, 2))` <- that's how I'm using it. `s(x)` is the function `x*sp.sin(3.0/x)`.

Comment: answer updated using sympy this time

Answer (score 1):

This takes about 30 seconds per `integrate` call:

```
import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol('x')

int2 = sp.integrate(x*sp.sin(3./x),(x,0.000001,2)).evalf(8)
print int2

int1 = sp.integrate(x*sp.sin(3./x),(x,0,2)).evalf(8)
print int1
```

The results are:

```
1.0996940
-4.5*Si(zoo) + 8.1682775
```

Clearly you want to start the integration from a small positive number to avoid the problem at x = 0.

You can also assign `x*sin(3./x)` to a variable, e.g.:

```
s = x*sin(3./x)
int1 = sp.integrate(s, (x, 0.00001, 2))
```

My original answer using scipy to compute the integral:

```
import scipy.integrate
import math

def s(x):
  if abs(x) < 0.00001:
    return 0
  else:
    return x*math.sin(3.0/x)

s_exact = scipy.integrate.quad(s,  0, 2)

print s_exact
```

See [the scipy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/integrate.html) for more integration options.

Comment: But this may not satisfy OPs goal of using SymPy which sounds like it may be a course requirement.

Comment: Ah - sp = sympy not scipy.

Comment: I think I've answer the OP's question using sympy this time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SymPy's integrate, you need a symbolic function. A wrong value at a point doesn't really matter for integration (at least mathematically), so you shouldn't worry about it.

It seems there is a bug in SymPy that gives an answer in terms of `zoo` at 0, because it isn't using `limit` correctly. You'll need to compute the limits manually. For example, the integral from 0 to 1:

```
In [14]: res = integrate(x*sin(3/x), x)

In [15]: ans = limit(res, x, 1) - limit(res, x, 0)

In [16]: ans
Out[16]:
  9⋅π   3⋅cos(3)   sin(3)   9⋅Si(3)
- ─── + ──────── + ────── + ───────
   4       2         2         2

In [17]: ans.evalf()
Out[17]: -0.164075835450162
```

Comment: I have a fix for the direct `integrate(x*sin(3/x), (x, 0, 1))` at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/8629.